# Could not resolve dependency from local repo in POM

Tags: maven, java-8, pom.xml

Hi I am trying to add a local jar file to maven dependency like below in POM.xml.

```
<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>project-repo</id>
    <url>file://C:/POC/Projects/Jar</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
```

I am always getting below error.

```
Could not find artifact cas:cas:jar:1.2 in project-repo (file://C:/POC/Projects/Jar)
```

How i can fix this issue?

Comment: Have you installed your JAR to the local repo? If not, try executing `mvn deploy:deploy-file`
  `-DgroupId=[group]` 
  `-DartifactId=[artifact]` 
  `-Dversion=[vers]` 
  `-DrepositoryId=project-repo`
  `-Dfile=[JAR_FILE_PATH] `

Comment: Can you add this as a answer, When i try this i got an error for https , then i changed settings xml to use https repo . Then it installed jar file and started working .

Comment: Added as an answer. Do accept to help others. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JAR needs to be installed to the local repo.

Executing the command below will install the JAR to local repo:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=[group] -DartifactId=[artifact] -Dversion=[vers] -DrepositoryId=project-repo -Dfile=[JAR_FILE_PATH]
```